# Font Awesome not Displaying

Tags: php, html

Any pointers please why Font Awesome icons are not displaying on my Wordpress site when I put them inside a php function?

```
<div class="navigation pull-right">
<?php
previous_post_link('%link', "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>" );
echo ' ';
```

They display fine on my site when not in php...

Comment: what does the function `previous_post_link()` do ?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying I've been struggling with this for ages!  It links to the previous post in the blogroll as in this web-page -  at the bottom see the two arrows.  If you view in IE or Firefox the arrows aren't displaying and that's why I want to replace them with Font Awesome icons.  http://www.photomobil.co.il/english-wedding-in-israel-bayaar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Put this in your head tag**

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
```

**Make changes in header.php file**

```
<?php
//* Do NOT include the opening php tag

//* Load Font Awesome
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_font_awesome' );
function enqueue_font_awesome() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

}
```

Comment: It's there already.  I have other Font Awesome icons displaying fine (e.g. the social icons top right) but it seems something about the php is stopping it from displaying.    The css is fine I've checked it and it works - but not here...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a change of the quotes help, like this:

```
previous_post_link("%link", '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
```